# django makemessages can't translate all words

Tags: django, internationalization, makemessages

makemessages can't detect all translation words... I tried all but it didn't work.

My command

```
django-admin makemessages --all --ignore=venv
# and
python manage.py makemessages --all --ignore=venv
```

My template

```
{% load i18n %}
{% trans 'тестовый какой-то текст' %}
{% trans 'Республика Узбекистан, г.Ташкент, Шайхонтохурский район, улица' %}
```

makemessages detected first text but not second... Pls help

Comment: if it can't detect the text, you can just write it yourself in the translation file. just add it to the file after you makemessages

Comment: hm... like this?
```django.po
#: .\path\to\template\text
msgid "some text"
msgstr "some translated text"
```